# hasKey doesn't see the field in the response

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured, autotest

I have test:

```
   @Test
   public void sixTest() {
       FlowerList flowerList = new FlowerList();
       Specification.installSpec(Specification.requestSpec(), Specification.responseSpec());
       Response response = given()
                .when()
                .get("/api/unknown")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .body("data.year", hasKey("2001"))
                .extract().response().as((Type) FlowerList.class);
```

I need to check that at least one year field contained the value 2001. But I get an exception:

```
Expected: map containing ["2001,"->ANYTHING]
  Actual: [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]
```

What am I doing wrong? In theory hasKey should return a single value 2001

get:

```
{
    page: 1,
    per_page: 6,
    total: 12,
    total_pages: 2,
    data: [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "cerulean",
    year: 2000,
    color: "#98B2D1",
    pantone_value: "15-4020"
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "fuchsia rose",
    year: 2001,
    color: "#C74375",
    pantone_value: "17-2031"
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message give you the answers

```
Expected: map containing ["2001,"->ANYTHING]
  Actual: [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]
```

The actual result is an array, instead of a map. hence
[`Matchers.hasItems`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasItems(T...)) (match if `Iterable` has items)
should be used instead of
[`Matchers.hasKeys`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasKey(K)) (match if the `Map` has key)

Another problem is, since `year` is Integer, `2001` should be the expected value instead of `"2001"`.

So the assertion should be

```java
.body("data.year", hasItems(2001))
```